# Is it possible to turn this code snippet in a list comprehension? How?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
a = 0
b = {'a': [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')], 'b': [(4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]}

for c, d in b.iteritems():
    for e, f in d:
        a += e

// now a = 15
```

Tried several ways. I want to know a way (if possible) to simplify this sum with a list comprehension:

`a = sum(...)`

Thank you in advance,
pf.me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a = sum(e for d in b.itervalues() for e, _ in d)` works in Python 2.7.

`a = sum([e for d in b.itervalues() for e, _ in d])` works in Python 2.3.

I haven't tried it, but `a = sum(e for d in b.values() for e, _ in d)` should be the Python 3.0 equivalent.

Comment: Cool that you shrinked 2 more chars using `itervalues()` instead of `iteritems()`. Good idea! :)

Comment: What's amusing to me is that the seemingly equivalent [e for e, _ in d for d in b.itervalues()] does not work - at least in Python 2.3. The "for" statements are apparently applied iteratively to whatever value is currently associated with that variable, rather than what should be functionally derived.

Comment: @pf.me: The point of using `itervalues` is that values are all that are needed--not to "shrink code".

Comment: Can't we just use sum(e[0] for d in b.itervalues() for e in d) [because we dont use _ too] :)

Answer (score 1):

`sum(j for _,i in b.iteritems() for j,_ in i)` will do it.